Muffle Effect in pyaudio
Hi I am working on a python VOIP application using sockets. Currently I have a working connection that allows two devices to "call" each other. I want to add some effects to the voices in the program, specifically a muffle effect that makes it sound like you are on the other side of a wall. This is the code that I have come up with so far.
import socket
import threading
import pyaudio

# Constants
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
HANDSHAKE_PORT = 5000
VOICE_PORT = 5001

def audio_stream(s, stream, is_receiving):
    while True:
        if is_receiving:
            data = s.recv(CHUNK)
            if not data:
                break
            stream.write(data)
        else:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            s.sendall(data)

def start_voip(server_ip, voice_port=VOICE_PORT):
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # Start the stream
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    output=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((server_ip, voice_port))

    send_thread = threading.Thread(target=audio_stream, args=(s, stream, False))
    recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=audio_stream, args=(s, stream, True))
    send_thread.start()
    recv_thread.start()

    send_thread.join()
    recv_thread.join()
    s.close()
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

def main(server_ip, handshake_port=HANDSHAKE_PORT):
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((server_ip, handshake_port))
    
    peer_ip = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    client_socket.close()
    
    # Connect to the server for voice data transfer
    start_voip(server_ip, VOICE_PORT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_ip = input("Enter the server IP address: ")
    main(server_ip)

My approach for this was to use a low pass filter, however my implementation doesn't work very well.
# Low-pass filter parameters
CUTOFF_FREQ = 1000  # Cutoff frequency in Hz
FILTER_ORDER = 6    # Order of the Butterworth filter

def butter_lowpass(cutoff, rate, order=5):
    nyquist = 0.5 * rate
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyquist
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    return b, a

def low_pass_filter(data, b, a, zi):
    data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    y, zo = lfilter(b, a, data, zi=zi)
    return y.astype(np.int16).tobytes(), zo

While it seems to apply a muffle effect, the low pass filter adds lots of static and fuzziness, ruining the audio quality. I am not well versed when it comes to audio so if anyone could help me out I would appreciate it.
